# Quoting strings for use in command line

Tags: zsh

I have a for loop that builds up a string to be converted to a series of arguments for a command on the command line.

the loop looks like:

```
lineSpecs=""
for tripWire in {1..$numTrips}
do
  lineSpec="-stroke ${colors[$tripWire+1]:0} -draw 'stroke-width 3 line $topX,$topY $botX,$botY'"
    
  lineSpecs="${lineSpecs} ${lineSpec}"
done
```

I then want to execute this command with:

```
magick "$inputImage" $lineSpecs $outputImage
```

It should look like:

`magick 'input.jpeg' -stroke purple -draw 'stroke-width 3 line 69,188 304,387' -stroke red -draw 'stroke-width 3 line 176,158 429,303' PaintedImage.jpg`

but it fails because the string is parsed as:

`magick 'input.jpeg' ' -stroke purple -draw '\''stroke-width 3 line 69,188 304,387'\'' -stroke red -draw '\''stroke-width 3 line 176,158 429,303'\' PaintedImage.jpg`

How to remove the erroneous quoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what arrays are for.

```
lineSpecs=()
for tripWire  in {1..$numTrips}
do
  lineSpec+=(-stroke ${colors[$tripWire+1]:0} -draw "stroke-width 3 line $topX,$topY $botX,$botY"')    
done

magic "$inputImage" $lineSpecs $outputImage
```

Comment: Amazing will test now

Answer (score 1):

Of course using an array, as chepner suggested in his answer, is the most convenient approach, but if for whatever reason you have to stick with your string, you can peruse it with

```
magic $inputImage ${(z)lineSpecs} $outputImage
```

The `(z)` takes care of interpolating the string properly into the command line.